# SMACSS based CSS Frameworks

Tags: css, frameworks

The SMACSS framework introduces a consistent way to manage your CSS code so that it is reusable and maintainable, but it is more of a guideline of how to organize your CSS rather than an actual framework. It would be nice if there were any other frameworks that were based off of its philosophy, but I haven't come across any.

Does anyone know of any CSS frameworks that are based off of the SMACSS method of organizing CSS code?

Comment: +1 good question, I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pure](http://purecss.io) is a newer CSS framework that is based on SMACSS. It seems to be related to the YUI project.

From their [extend page](http://purecss.io/extend/)...

> **Based on SMACSS**
>
> Pure is broken up into a set of responsive modules. From the beginning, we adopted SMACSS as a convention for writing our CSS. For those who are new to SMACSS, you should give it a quick read, especially the section on module rules.

Comment: You sir are king! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Since no answers are flying off the press, I was curious and took a look around.

It turns out there are [quite a few](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&rlz=1C2ASUT_enUS444US460&sclient=psy-ab&q=organize+css&oq=organize+css&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.4821.8867.0.8988.21.12.0.0.0.0.371.371.3-1.1.0...0.0.6zmK-_Cv2FU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b4c92a2d29177826&biw=1366&bih=635), [and I see you have been at this for a while now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038080/structured-way-to-organize-css-code).

[I see others recommended LESS or SASS](http://railslove.com/blog/2012/03/28/smacss-and-sass-the-future-of-stylesheets/), and I'll add there are solutions like Compass and Susy. These are simply things to look into as they each have inherent organization patterns.

But here is my actual answer.

I have a similar endeavor in looking for CSS frameworks that organize the resulting solutions of Responsive Web Design, into best-practices, naming-conventions and otherwise -- patterns. [So here is what I was looking at](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/), with an equivlent open-ended question, at a dead-end.

I considered that perhaps the problem may be, that CSS organization is highly dependent on environment and context. [So, maybe design patterns is a good approach](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&rlz=1C2ASUT_enUS444US460&sclient=psy-ab&q=css+design+patterns&oq=css+design+patterns&gs_l=serp.3...20726.21741.1.22019.7.6.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.oMJTZFPDsvc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b4c92a2d29177826&biw=1366&bih=635).

So here was my solution and I will suggest it here -> I really like your comments on separating css into: base, layout, fonts, elements. This can benefit others in some instances.

*If you cannot find a organization methodology out there that suits your environment, experiment and design what you need, then name it, and share it back with the world.*

This is multiply beneficial to you, in that: you learn how to solve your problem, and it shows well for you as an advanced developer.

One approach is to share the solution in a wordpress blog, a website example page, or a github repository.

If it is genuine and beneficial, name it, build it and share it.
Only good things can come of this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that Bootstrap is *based* on SMACSS, but Jonathan Snook (SMACSS founder) had the following to say:

> "If you were wondering what an example implementation of SMACSS might look like? Bootstrap is a perfect example."

[Prefixed classes in bootstrap](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/prefixed-classes-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the term SMACSS as a synonym for [**OOCSS**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/) or [**Atomic design**](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/), consider the following frameworks :

- [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/)
- [**Scally**](https://github.com/chris-pearce/scally)
- [**InuitCSS**](https://github.com/inuitcss)

Answer (score 0):

SMACSS is a convention of writing CSS. so the frameworks themselves are not important if they are following this convention or not. YOU are the one who should follow SMACSS when using ANY framework.

for example, someone made some .LESS files with comments for anyone who is willing to use LESS with SMACSS: https://github.com/growdigital/LESS-SMACSS

Answer (score 0):

You should try **Helpers CSS**: http://helpers.araujo.cc/

Very easy to learn and understand.

```
<p text="gray-80 normal center">
 <span text="bold big line-1 red">
    Can you
  </span> feel the
  <span text="underline italic blue semi-bold">
    future
  </span>? HTML6
  <span text="pre white-80 line-1.5" layout="navy few-rounded inline-block">  advantages  </span>
   are expecting for
   <span text="bolder">you</span>!
</p>
```